# Why is Telescope failing to run?

Tags: meteor, telescope

I followed the directions to install Telescope from the website but am getting the following errors at the end:

```
While building the application:
error: no such package: 'crypto-md5'
error: no such package: 'momentjs'
error: no such package: 'iron-router'
error: no such package: 'fast-render'
error: no such package: 'spin'
error: no such package: 'autoform'
error: no such package: 'collection2'
error: no such package: 'jquery-hotkeys'
error: no such package: 'marked'
error: no such package: 'bootstrap3-datepicker'
error: no such package: 'subs-manager'
error: no such package: 'telescope-module-embedly'
error: no such package: 'handlebars-server'
error: no such package: 'npm'
error: no such package: 'mailchimp'
error: no such package: 'synced-cron'
error: no such package: 'cookies'
error: no such package: 'telescope-newsletter'
While building package telescope-tags: error: no such package: 'simple-schema' error: no such package: 'iron-router'
While building package telescope-search: error: no such package: 'simple-schema' error: no such package: 'iron-router'
=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change."
```

My machine is running RHEL6. I plan on setting it up for my group behind the firewall and can't use any 3rd party services for it. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: sounds like it hasn't fetched all the packages

Comment: what version of meteor are you using?

Comment: How do I fetch all the packages? Did I miss a step?

Comment: I have never installed telescope myself, so I'm just guessing.   Meteorite is the thing that will get the packages

Comment: instead of running meteor,  try running  mrt

Comment: Clean the `packages` folder under your `$HOME/.meteor` and `$HOME/.meteorite`. Then re-run `mrt`.

Comment: mrt solved the problem - yay!